# Centering one out of multiple elements using text-align: center

Tags: html, css

Looking to center only one out of multiple elements within a div. The problem with assigning the div with text-align: center is that it targets them all. Is there an easy way of doing this?

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>Span 1</span>
    <br>
    <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {background: gray; width: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can target `:first-child` or `:last-child` on the `span` or use `nth-of-type(value-here)` if it's not the first or last but another one in the order

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/83cHK/)

Comment: Never realized the text-align property could be set to children elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the styling on the span, or give it an id/class and add `display:block` like so:

```
<div>
  <span id="span1">Span 1</span>
  <br>
  <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

```
#span1 {
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3wHH9/1/

Comment: The goal is to center only one of the two.